# What is the issue with my code to upload image in the users form?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a MySQL and PHP project where I've created a form to capture user details, including their passport. However, when users fill out the form and click submit, the page goes blank, and the data doesn't get inserted into the database. Strangely, the image does get moved to the specified directory. I need help resolving this issue to ensure everything works smoothly. Below are my codes, with the primary problem being the picture uploading.

Here's the relevant PHP and HTML code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$regno=$_POST['regno']; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];
$status=1;
// image file directory
    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);


$sql="INSERT INTO  tblstudents(name,image,regno,email,password,status) VALUES(:name,:image,:regno,:email,:password, :status)";

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':image',$_image,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':regno',$regno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
$Id = $dbh->Id();
if($Id)
{
$msg="user added successfully";
}

elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
}else 
{
$error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
}

}
?>
```

Here is my html form

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <!-- image file  enctype="multipart/form-data" -->

<div class="form-group">
<label for="default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Registration Number</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="regno" class="form-control" id="regno" maxlength="50" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label for="default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>



<!-- passport to upload -->

<div class="form-group">
<label for="default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Passport</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">     
</div>      
</div>                               
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
```

Comment: 1) Why are you running `move_uploaded_file` twice?

Comment: 2) `it went blank`...probably means it crashed somewhere, but you haven't got error reporting switched on. Turn on PHP's main error reporting, and also PDO exception handling, so that you can see more clearly what's going on. (You can easily google how to do both of those things, if you don't know).

Comment: When I comment one move_uploaded_file, the image was not saved inside the folder

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense. You only need to execute it once.

Comment: Please share your HTML form too.

Comment: I have added my html form

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved the issue and it is working perfectly now. I used array to captured all the varibales.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).